# How to read data from xlsx (instead of formulas) in python?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I will start by posting the code example that's been used to create a testcase (foo.xlsx) for this thread.

This simple code creates an xlsx file with numerical entries and formulas:

```
[boris@E7490-DELL temp]$ cat xlsx1.py
#!/bin/env python

import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [7, 2, 5, 9, 1], 'col2': [3, 6, 6, 7, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("foo.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df["prod"] = None
df["prod"] = (
    '=INDIRECT("R[0]C[%s]", 0)*INDIRECT("R[0]C[%s]", 0)'
    % (
        df.columns.get_loc("col1") - df.columns.get_loc("prod"),
        df.columns.get_loc("col2") - df.columns.get_loc("prod"),
    )
)
df["sum"] = None
df["sum"] = (
    '=SUM(INDIRECT("R[0]C[%s]:R[0]C[%s]",0))'
    % (
        df.columns.get_loc("col1") - df.columns.get_loc("sum"),
        df.columns.get_loc("col2") - df.columns.get_loc("sum"),
    )
)
df["max"] = None
df["max"] = (
    '=MAX(INDIRECT("R[0]C[%s]:R[0]C[%s]",0))'
    % (
        df.columns.get_loc("col1") - df.columns.get_loc("max"),
        df.columns.get_loc("col2") - df.columns.get_loc("max"),
    )
)
df["min"] = None
df["min"] = (
    '=MIN(INDIRECT("R[0]C[%s]:R[0]C[%s]",0))'
    % (
        df.columns.get_loc("col1") - df.columns.get_loc("min"),
        df.columns.get_loc("col2") - df.columns.get_loc("min"),
    )
)
print(df)

df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
```

CLI output after executing the above mentioned code, i.e. `print(df)`:

```
[boris@E7490-DELL temp]$ ./xlsx1.py
   col1  col2                                               prod                                      sum                                      max                                      min
0     7     3  =INDIRECT("R[0]C[-2]", 0)*INDIRECT("R[0]C[-1]"...  =SUM(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-3]:R[0]C[-2]",0))  =MAX(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-4]:R[0]C[-3]",0))  =MIN(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-5]:R[0]C[-4]",0))
1     2     6  =INDIRECT("R[0]C[-2]", 0)*INDIRECT("R[0]C[-1]"...  =SUM(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-3]:R[0]C[-2]",0))  =MAX(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-4]:R[0]C[-3]",0))  =MIN(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-5]:R[0]C[-4]",0))
2     5     6  =INDIRECT("R[0]C[-2]", 0)*INDIRECT("R[0]C[-1]"...  =SUM(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-3]:R[0]C[-2]",0))  =MAX(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-4]:R[0]C[-3]",0))  =MIN(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-5]:R[0]C[-4]",0))
3     9     7  =INDIRECT("R[0]C[-2]", 0)*INDIRECT("R[0]C[-1]"...  =SUM(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-3]:R[0]C[-2]",0))  =MAX(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-4]:R[0]C[-3]",0))  =MIN(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-5]:R[0]C[-4]",0))
4     1     9  =INDIRECT("R[0]C[-2]", 0)*INDIRECT("R[0]C[-1]"...  =SUM(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-3]:R[0]C[-2]",0))  =MAX(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-4]:R[0]C[-3]",0))  =MIN(INDIRECT("R[0]C[-5]:R[0]C[-4]",0))
```

foo.xlsx file content (the screenshot shows the foo.xlsx as displayed by LibreOffice Calc)

[image: foo.xlsx file content]

So that's how my testcase (foo.xlsx) is created. This xlsx contains only numerical values, of which some are integers and some are calculated by formulas. Now I would like to read this xlsx file in pandas data-frame for post-processing (don't need the formulas, but the actual values calculated by the formulas).
I've tried two methods (both unsuccessful) that will be explained next...

**Method 1)** is using `pandas.read_excel`:

The Code:

```
[boris@E7490-DELL temp]$ cat xlsx2.py
#!/bin/env python

import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_excel("foo.xlsx")
print(read_file)

read_file.to_csv ("foo.csv", index = None, header=True)
```

CLI output:

```
[boris@E7490-DELL temp]$ ./xlsx2.py
   col1  col2  prod  sum  max  min
0     7     3     0    0    0    0
1     2     6     0    0    0    0
2     5     6     0    0    0    0
3     9     7     0    0    0    0
4     1     9     0    0    0    0
```

foo.csv file content:

```
[boris@E7490-DELL temp]$ cat foo.csv
col1,col2,prod,sum,max,min
7,3,0,0,0,0
2,6,0,0,0,0
5,6,0,0,0,0
9,7,0,0,0,0
1,9,0,0,0,0
```

**Method 2)** is using `openpyxl.load_workbook`:

The Code:

```
[boris@E7490-DELL temp]$ cat xlsx3.py
#!/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("foo.xlsx", data_only=True)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
print(df.head())

df.to_csv ("foo.csv", index = None, header=True)
```

CLI output:

```
[boris@E7490-DELL temp]$ ./xlsx3.py
      0     1     2    3    4    5
0  col1  col2  prod  sum  max  min
1     7     3     0    0    0    0
2     2     6     0    0    0    0
3     5     6     0    0    0    0
4     9     7     0    0    0    0
```

foo.csv file content:

```
[boris@E7490-DELL temp]$ cat foo.csv
0,1,2,3,4,5
col1,col2,prod,sum,max,min
7,3,0,0,0,0
2,6,0,0,0,0
5,6,0,0,0,0
9,7,0,0,0,0
1,9,0,0,0,0
```

Both methods have failed to get the numerical values out of the xlsx. I'm stuck here, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is entirely to be expected `data_only=True` will only give values if another application has calculated them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have an idea how to automate this further, I'll just go with a headless execution:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to csv foo.xlsx
```

foo.csv file content:

```
[boris@E7490-DELL temp]$ cat foo.csv
col1,col2,prod,sum,max,min
7,3,21,10,7,3
2,6,12,8,6,2
5,6,30,11,6,5
9,7,63,16,9,7
1,9,9,10,9,1
```

Then I'll be reading this csv file to pandas data-frame for post-processing.

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a workaround here, not a real explanation for what is happening, but...

I'm getting the same thing as you, but if I open the excel file and just save it, then reading it in pandas gives the numbers you want. So try that, just opening excel and saving it. You could easily enough script that.

Comment: The formulas aren't actually calculated when the file is written - opening Excel calculates them.

Comment: Yes I have the same answer as you. It's because formula haven't been assigned yet.

Comment: [Xlsxwriter doesn't calculate formulas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html). "XlsxWriter doesn’t calculate the result of a formula and instead stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be recalculated when the file is opened."

Comment: The real question is why OP is using formulas/Excel to do this at all, rather than just pure pandas.

Comment: @BigBen Totally, agree but in this case it is not my decision to make. I'm automating data entry in a huge xlsx file (several hundred values), the result is calculated by the formulas, some users of the xlsx still want to be able to modify the input values manually in the xls spreadsheet.
In short, I'm trying to make my life easier, while other people don't mind doing dumb monotonous work.

Comment: uggh. Well in any case seems you need to actually engage the Excel calculation engine.

Comment: @BigBen I would very much like to avoid that. Is there a way to instruct XlsxWriter (or openpyxl) to calculate formulas before writing (reading) the file?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with those libraries. I don't think Xlsxwriter or openpyxl have re-created the Excel calculation engine.

Comment: @BorisL. no it isn't. `xlwings` can be used to automate opening the file and allowing Excel to calculate formulas. You could then save the file and reopen it in `openpyxl` with `data_only=True`